# Session level authentication in MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I am uploading audio file in chunks from a Windows Phone client to an MVC3 application

I have written a Controller with an `HttpPost` attribute decorated Action, that is processing an incoming chunks.

The action's signature is:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RecieveChunk(string id, [ModelBinder(typeof(AudioChunkModelBinder))] byte[] audio)
```

`id` in this case, is an id of a file upload session, that presumably will get negotioated by client and server before actual chunk `POST`s will come pouring in.

On the Windows Phone side, an instance of `HttpWebRequest` is doing the upload work with no authentication currently in place.

On the server, I need to be able to know, from whom each post is coming from.

Is there a way for me to obtain a some kind of an access token from an MVC3 site to be able to POST to a site's specific Uri, but without a need to send a user ID and a Password as a part of a Uri?

What can be an authentication approach for me in my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're authenticating with the built-in ASP.NET / MVC authentication mechanisms, you can check the `User.Identity` on the server (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewfkf772.aspx) to get information about the current user.

This assumes, of course, that you're using the [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx) property of `HttpWebRequest` to persist authentication data between requests.